# Use jquery to Append streaming video from a php page containing basically object tags. when different links for videos are clicked

Tags: jquery, append

Im a newbie to jquery.
I really require assistance with putting jquery in my code

i have some links i.e. link1 link2 link3

i also have a div tag `<div class="vid"></div>` WHICH IS WHERE THE VIDEOS OBTAINED WILL BE APPENDED.

I have a php page that fetches A STREAMING video with an `<object>` tag FROM MANY 4 IP CAMERAS

what i'm trying to do is when i click on the link[i] with `href="page?ip="ipadd`, i want the video jquery to fetch the page that calls the video and APPEND it to the div tag.

I was thinking of being able to send a get request with the ip address (which is the href on the links) to the php page handling the video, so it can use the ip address to pick the correct video from the correct video (IM STREAMING THEM FROM AN IP CAMERA.) That is why i want to use jquery to load each video as the link is being clicked. But i really have no clue on how that works.

---

Ok Gaby i have added a line check my sample page now i added the

```
 $('a.video-link').click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault(); ....}
```

my page now becomes

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsfile.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<a href="akin3.html" class="video-link" >link 1</a>
...

<div class="vid" >
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.video-link').click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
  // get the contents of the clicked Url and then append them at the div with class vid
  $.get( this.href, 
         function(data){  
               $('.vid').append( data ); 
         }
       );
  return false;
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but when i click on the link it appends. if i try to click a link that i have clicked previously, it clears the div tag and jumps to the link that i an clicking the second time. i need it to append that link still(being able to append a link multiple time). any help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a class to your links for example `video-link`

```
<a href=".." class="video-link">link 1</a>
<a href=".." class="video-link">link 2</a>
```

and use

```
$('a.video-link').click(function(){
  // load and put the contents of the url in the div with class vid
  $('div.vid').load( this.href );
  return false;
});
```

reference: the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method

The above solution will **replace** the contents of the `vid` div.

---

If you want to **append** it at the end (*keeping the current contents*) then use

```
$('a.video-link').click(function(){
  // get the contents of the clicked Url and then append them at the div with class vid
  $.get( this.href, 
         function(data){  
               $('div.vid').append( data ); 
         }
       );
  return false;
});
```

reference: the [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method

Comment: +1 - but if he actually means *append* then he might have to use `$.get` and call `.append`.

Comment: Thanks Gabby. The second example is a little like it. However, It jumps to the link address when i click on it. I was also thinking of being able to send a get the ip address (which is the href on the links) to the php page handling the video, so it can use the ip address to pick the correct video from the correct video (IM ACTUALLY STREAMING THEM FROM AN IP CAMERA.) That is why i want to use jquery to load each video as the link is being clicked. Thanks man

Comment: @2me, ah.. forgot the `return false;` at the end of the handler to cancel the default behavior of the link (*cancel sending you to the actual page*). updated answer.

Comment: @Gaby. it still jumps to the external page.

Comment: @2me, is the jquery wrapped inside the `$(document).ready(function(){...});` event function ? otherwise the DOM might not be ready when we assign the click handler.

Comment: i just tried it even with a very simple script. it didn't work   <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.video-link').click(function(){
  // get the contents of the clicked Url and then append them at the div with class vid
  $.get( this.href, 
         function(data){  
               $('.vid').append( data ); 
         }
       );
  return false;
});
});
</script>

Comment: @2me, have you added the class `video-link` to the links ? Do you get any javascript errors with firebug?

Comment: OK i had to install wamp over again. and it works well. Im so grateful. However, when i click on the first link, it appends, if i click any other link again, it jumps to the page.

Comment: Ok Gabby i have added a line check my sample page now

Comment: @Gaby thanks really for your assistance. i posted an answer, please check it i still have a problem with it. when i click on a link it appends. if i click the same link 2ce. it jumps to thaat page i added a little change to it i added::     $(document).ready(function(){ $('a.video-link').click(function (event) { event.preventDefault();

Comment: @2me, `.preventDefault()` should do the same thing as `return false;`. Can you set up a page online somewhere, so we can see it in action. The current code should work as is. The problem might be somewhere else. For example a javascript error at some other place might be stopping javascript from getting executed and thus you follow the links. Try using a firebug, or some browser debugging tools to see if any javascript errors occur.